# How much energy is lost per bounce with a tennis ball?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics, collision, dissipation

When a tennis ball bounces it loses some energy. How much energy or height is lost per bounce?

Comment: Well, what do you think? Are you familiar with the "coefficient of restitution"? Check out the Wikipedia article.

Comment: It depends on which brand of tennis ball. Drop a tennis ball from some height and measure how high it bounces up. That fractional height is the same as the fractional energy it still has.

Comment: Less than silly-putty and more than a lacrosse ball?

Answer (score 2):

Measure it! Drop a tennis ball from $1$ meter and then measure as close as possible the height of its bounce. Use the simple potential energy of near Earth gravity $V=mgh$ to find what percentage of energy remained on the bounce. You can try various initial heights to see if that scale proportionately.